# How to declare a class explicity abstract?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, abstract

I am looking at the following:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr142.htm

and it says an abstract class in C++ contains a pure virtual function. However, surely this does not mean to create an abstract class all I do is insert a pure virtual function? Couldn't I have the situation where I have a concrete class which doesn't provide an implementation for one particular function and therefore makes it abstract, forcing derived classes to provide the implementation? This wouldn't make the class abstract though?

So how do I differentiate between "this is an abstract class" and "this is a concrete class with one pure virtual function"?

Comment: Question is a little unclear/confusing. You state quite clearly that you've understood that an abstract class must contain a pure virtual function. That is the requirement. If you don't have a pure virtual function, your class is not abstract. So are you asking if that's correct?

Comment: Yes, having at least one pure virtual function makes the class abstract. [Reading this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type#Signifying_abstract_types) might help you.

Comment: @kfsone are you saying a concrete class cannot contain a pure virtual function?

Comment: set the virtual funcs to 0 too.

Comment: @BobBlogge setting a virtual function to be 0, is making it pure virtual.

Comment: I think as long as a class completely implements an abstract then it's concrete.  But it can also contain a pure virtual itself from which another concrete (or abstract) can inherit, making it concrete for the derived but abstract for those which derive from it.

Comment: @user997112 I'm saying - as you already have - that adding a pure virtual function to a class makes the class an abstract class. Once you provide an implementation for all your pvf's your class is concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class is extactly then abstract when it has one or more pure virtual function. If you write a (base) class, wich has all functions implemented, and thus can be instantiated, but it misses a vital function, then it is simply wrong design of your class. 
Your base class wouldn't be complete in this case and the pure virtual uninmplemented function should be added, which makes it an abstract class then.

If you have a derived class, which derives from an abstract class, and doesn't implement all functions from the base class, then it is in turn also abstract. In this case, it wouldn't need a pure virtual function itself, because it is abstract by inheritance.

There is no `abstract` keyword in `C++`, like in `Java` to indicate that a class is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated above, an abstract class in C++ is, by definition, a class which has at least one pure virtual function. The class being abstract means that you can't make instances of it (only of "concrete" classes derived from it), which protects you from calling the "unexistent" pure virtual functions (although technically you can still call them from base class constructor/destructor and get a nasty runtime crash).

There are no explicit "interface" kind of classes in C++, so you are free to provide implementation for some functions in any classes as you wish, regardless of whether the class is already abstract due to some other function being pure virtual.

On a side note, I'd still like to point out one way to make your class abstract without actually making any "real" methods pure virtual. It is enough to make the class **destructor** pure virtual (note that it is generally a good idea for the destructor of any polymorphic class to be virtual anyway). A minor gotcha here is that in this particular case (only for destructor), you will still have to provide an implementation for it for the linker to be happy. It may look like this:

```
class A // abstract class
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = 0 {} // destructor is pure virtual, but still needs a body
};

class B : public A {}; // concrete class deriving from an abstract class
```

Also note that in this particular case, class B does not have to explicitly implement its own destructor to become concrete, so, if you'd like it to be abstract too, you'll have to repeat the same trick again (or add some other pure virtual methods to B).

Comment: Interesting trick :) But I have a follow-up question: There's also a trick with making the constructor private. This also makes the class impossible to instantiate by the "outside world" (though it still can be instantiated internally by the class's methods or the class's friends). How do these two techniques differ and which is better in which particular situations?

Comment: @SasQ If you mark all constructors `private` for a class, there won't be any point in making it abstract: no derived class would ever be able to construct itself, as it has to call one of the base constructors first. Of course, you might use `protected` instead. There are valid reasons for private constructors too, although they have nothing to do with abstract classes. Singletons typically use them along with a private destructor. They are also useful to ensure that your class objects are always created dynamically and never on stack: just provide a public static method with a `new` inside.

Comment: You're right, I should have said "non-public" instead of "private", because that's what I meant. `protected` is included in this category, so derived classes can call such constructors.

Comment: As to making constructors `private` to prevent constructing them on the stack: I don't think this gonna work. They can still be created on the stack inside all static member functions of its own class, and by its friends. It's only the outside world which cannot.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. :) Any class surely has a right to do whatever it wants with itself, that's called "implementation details". But designing interface for the outside world in a way that prevents errors by class users is still very helpful. When you design a new class, you probably already know whether it's safe to create it on stack, and you write your code accordingly. However, some other user of this class (or yourself, after a long break) might not know that... until they see private constructors + a static create method, which make the intention obvious and enforce compliance.

Comment: Regarding protected constructors. If a class is already abstract, then I don't see any real difference between public and protected constructors: attempting to call them outside of a derived class construction process will result in a compile error in both cases (just different errors). I, however, usually make them protected just to keep things clear.

Comment: And if a class is intended for inheritance only, but doesn't have any virtual functions which can be used to make it abstract (not even a virtual destructor)... well... that's not a very frequent case, is it? :) Though, actually, I do have such classes myself. Empty ones, combined with some template magic to achieve polymorphic behavor for objects that I don't want to make polymorphic for optimization reasons (this is related to serialization). But again, when a class is empty and its constructor is trivial, there seems to be no real difference in whether you can create an instance of it.

Comment: What if you want to provide an abstract base class with some default implementations of all its virtual methods which derived classes can override or use the defaults? The class is not intended for instantiation, but those default implementations make those functions not pure virtual, and this in turn prevents the class from being abstract. I recall that in this case I regret that C++ doesn't have `abstract` keyword like Java does.

Comment: You have a point here, but is this case really such a frequent one? And, if the base class really has safe and meaningful default implementations for all of its methods, then what's the tragedy in allowing to make an instance of it? Of course, if you feel there's a reason to prohibit that, marking all constructors protected seems to be enough of a solution. As I already said, that's what I'm usually doing for base-only classes anyway, regardless of whether they are abstract or not.

Comment: Because it can be nonsensical to create an instance of such a class from the logical point of view, even if there are no practical problems with it. It's similar to the question about brute casting pointers: sure, one can do that in practice, and it works (most of the time), but there are better ways for conversions, which make more sense, and let the compiler help you keep track of everything. Right?